# 302 error on $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to load a page using the $.get function. Suddenly I'm getting 302 errors. It worked fine last time I checked. When I open the page I want to load in my browser, it works fine. Maybe because I upgraded to firefox 5.0. Is there a fix for this?
Thanks, Rik

Answer (score 2):

302 is not an error.  It simply means that the resource is at a different URI.  See [this document on HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Answer (score 1):

302 is not an error, but a response code meaning that the page is to be found elsewhere.

Comment: The response is coming from the server you're talking to, so you'd need to look there.

Comment: A 302 response is very common, although I'd figure this is normally handled by JQuery itself. Does anything go wrong? Can you post additional information about it (example code and the url, if possible).

Answer (score 0):

The document is in your cache. you can try clean your cache or put a random parameter to the end of the url string like this: `http://my.url.com/mypage.asp.php?random=xxxx` where each query xxxx is a diferent random number.